# How to unit test the expression being passed into the repository layer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, repository

I have a service layer which calls a repository layer to fetch data, then do work upon the return object.  I want to test the expression being sent into the repository "get" method, say in case the primary key becomes a compound key or something.

Example:

```
public async Task ArchiveAsync(Domain.Person person)
{
    Data.Person entityModel = await _repo.SingleOrDefaultAsync<Data.Person>(p => p.Id == person.Id);

    // Stuff is done here...
}
```

So, in this example, the domain object is passed in, the data object is fetched, and something is done to it.  I want to test the expression being passed into the `SingleOrDefaultAsync` method.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to refactor your code and make the "expression" a proper entity.
The [Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) pattern is perfect for your case.

Vladimir Khorikov has written a great,simple article about this: [Specification pattern: C# implementation](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/02/08/specification-pattern-c-implementation/)

He has a sample project published on GitHub [here](https://github.com/vkhorikov/SpecificationPattern)

In case the link becomes invalid,I add the main core logic here.
Your repository will look like this:

```
public IReadOnlyList<T> Find(Specification<T> specification)
{
        using (context))
        {
            return context.DbSet<T>()
                .Where(specification.ToExpression())
                .ToList();
        }
}
```

For the Specification class you can find many implementations.
It a small utility class that is converted to an expression eventually

If you design your app like that you can easily Test your Specification(which practically is your expression)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's a good idea to test expressions. But you may try, if you wish. I have at least one idea for such request.

It will be required to provide a mock instead of your repository, you may use any library you wish. [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) or [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) as an example.

Then, you should get `Expression<Func<Domain.Person, bool>>` object passed to your repository on `SingleOrDefaultAsync` invocation. That's should be pretty straightforward with most mocking libs.

And for the last, you will need to compile your expression into `Func<Domain.Person, bool>` and assert that it returns `true` for `Domain.Person` object with expected `Id` and `false` otherwise.

And a small snapshot to illustrate, I'm assuming here that there is only one argument, there is the only invocation on repository object and that `Domain.Person.Id` has public setter.

```
var repository = Substitute.For<IRepository>();
var service = new Service(repository);
var person = new Domain.Person { Id = 42 };

await service.ArchiveAsync(person);

var call = repository.ReceivedCalls().First();
var arg = call.GetArguments().First();
var expr = (Expression<Func<Domain.Person, bool>>)arg;
var func = expr.Compile();

Assert.True(func(person));
Assert.False(func(new Domain.Person {Id = 1}));
```